# Why is a pointer on an ivar bad in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, properties, ivar

I am reading ["Effective Objective-C 2.0: 52 Specific Ways to Improve Your iOS and OS X Programs"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321917014). In "Item 6", the author says that using a pointer on a public ivar is a bad idea, because compiled code will have hardcoded pointer offset, and when new ivar will be added to class, then previously used pointers to some ivars can now point on other variable.

```
@interface Foo
{
    @public
    NSString * string;
    NSArray * arr;
}
@end

@implementation
...
@end

int main()
{
  @autoreleasepool
  {
   Foo *f=[Foo new];
   f->string; //Is it bad idea?
  }

 return 0;
}
```

But, aren't ivars and properties dynamic (offset is not known at compile-time)? As [Cocoa With Love](http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2010/03/dynamic-ivars-solving-fragile-base.html) says:

> "All ivars are dynamic in the modern runtime: Since this procedure is followed for all ivars, that means that all ivars in the modern Objective-C runtime are dynamic in that their absolute offsets are never known at compile-time."

If that's true, then why is using a pointer on an ivar bad? Please provide as much low-level detail as possible.

Comment: Question:  Is he talking about having a public ivar that is a pointer, or rather talking about taking the address (`&`) of a public ivar?

Comment: Meh, just use properties. Everything sorted.

Comment: Easy as PIE. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1788/_index.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> If that's true, then why is using a pointer on an ivar bad? Please
>   provide as much low-level detail as possible.

Because it breaks encapsulation.

What if class `Foo` has some custom logic that should be fired when `string` changes?  Or it has to do a calculation?  Or `Foo` wants to make the storage of `string` unique-ified?  Or something else wants to observe changes to said property?  Or `Foo` wants to change the storage semantics later?  Or someone wants to subclass `Foo` and change the behavior there?

Answer (score 2):

Not a problem: "All instance variables in 64-bit Objective-C are non-fragile. That is, existing compiled code that uses a class's ivars will not break when the class or a superclass changes its own ivar layout. In particular, framework classes may add new ivars without breaking subclasses compiled against a previous version of the framework." (https://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/mac/releasenotes/Cocoa/RN-ObjectiveC/index.html)

This also holds for the 32 bit modern runtime, of course.

Apart from the implementation technicalities, it's an exceptionally bad design though, as bbum notes.

Comment: Bluffer's guide: that means it's true across all iOS devices since time immemorial and on 64-bit Intel (so, definitely anything running OS X v10.7 or later, plus many earlier machines).

Comment: No;  direct access of instance variables is a horrible idea and beyond strongly discouraged in Objective-C.  It yields difficult to maintain code that is extremely brittle to change.

Comment: @bbum, yes, but not for the reason alluded to in the question, right? By the way, ivar access inside the class's methods is still fine/unavoidable as far as I know.

Comment: @StevenKramer In OP's example, he is mucking with the iVar from outside the object, which is bad.   Yes, direct ivar access happens *within the class's implementation itself*, but that isn't a violation of encapsulation (and you don't generally use `self->` in that case, either).

Comment: Sure. I've updated my answer anyway to distinguish whether the example is well-formed (it is) and well-designed (it is not). By the way, people seem to be overusing `self.` a lot these days for properties. That breaks encapsulation too because it exposes implementation detail (an ivar that is only meant to be used inside the class) into invisible but accessible methods.